# Is there a way to tell if a URL is instantiated a 302, 301, or redirect via CNAME?

Tags: redirect, cname-record

My question sums it up. If I navigate to a certain URL, is there a way for me to tell as a user whether or not that domain name is CNAME'ing, or performing a 302/301?

Comment: If an http redirect (301/302) happens then the url changes. If there is a CNAME record then nothing changes. Is that what you were going for or can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `dig` / `nslookup` to check if the host is a CNAME, and use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see if you are redirected.

Answer (score 1):

no, unless you are watching the packet stream. A browser plugin could potentially let you know if you've hit a 30x redirect, but not a CNAME, only your dns resolver would be aware of that

Edit - I prefer MichelZ answer, was unaware of Fiddler. My answer was from the angle of a traditional user in a browser...